# django-pytest error creating test database containing many to many field

Tags: python, django, django-models, pytest-django

I have a model having many to many field like the following. I am using pytest to write unit test cases for it.

models.py

```
class CustomerMaster(models.Model):
    customer_key = models.IntegerField(db_column='CUSTOMER_KEY', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    first_name = models.TextField(db_column='FIRST_NAME', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    last_name = models.TextField(db_column='LAST_NAME', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    email = models.CharField(db_column='EMAIL', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    gender = models.TextField(db_column='GENDER', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dob = models.DateField(db_column='DOB', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    phone = models.CharField(db_column='PHONE', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    address = models.TextField(db_column='ADDRESS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
  ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'customer_master'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name

class Segment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    folder = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    selection = JSONField()
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    createdBy = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    contact = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerMaster)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I need to check if only the logged in user is able to acces the view. For that, I am using the @login_required decorator provided by the django itself. For creating a dummy user I am using the following fixture:

conftest.py

```
import uuid

import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def test_password():
   return 'strong-test-pass'

@pytest.fixture
def create_user(db, django_user_model, test_password):
   def make_user(**kwargs):
       kwargs['password'] = test_password
       if 'username' not in kwargs:
           kwargs['username'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
       return django_user_model.objects.create_user(**kwargs)
   return make_user

@pytest.fixture
def auto_login_user(db, client, create_user, test_password):
   def make_auto_login(user=None):
       if user is None:
           user = create_user()
       client.login(username=user.username, password=test_password)
       return client, user
   return make_auto_login
```

my test case:

```
    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_status(self, auto_login_user):
        client, user = auto_login_user()
        url = reverse("overview", kwargs={"pk": 1})
        response = client.get(url)
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

But while running this test case, pytest is giving me the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1824, "Failed to open the referenced table 'customer_master'")
```

When I checked my database, the test_img database is partially created having segment table but not customer_master. It is giving the error while creating the through table of many to many relationship table (i.e analytics_segment_contact) between the segment and the customer_master.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try running the tests with `--create-db` once? And do the migrations exist?

Comment: Yeah, I did but it is giving me the same error. And yes, the migrations exist.